# remote request from functions.php is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, wordpress-hook

I am writing a custom function for a **post_updated** action in wordpress like below:

```
function post_update_trigger($post_ID, $post_after, $post_before){

    if($post_after->post_status == "publish" || $post_after->post_status == "trash" ){

        $url="https://myremoteurl.com/feed/blogAPI";

       $response = wp_remote_post($url,array(
                         'method' => 'POST',
                         'timeout' => 45,
                         'redirection' => 5,
                         'httpversion' => '1.0',
                         'blocking' => true,
                         'headers' => array(),
                         'body' => $postFields,
                         'cookies' => array()
                       ));

           if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
                    $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
                    echo "Something went wrong: $error_message";exit;
            } else {
                    echo 'Response:<pre>';
                   print_r( $response );exit;
                   echo '</pre>';
    }

    }

}

add_action( 'post_updated', 'post_update_trigger', 10, 3 );
```

I tried the post request from postman. everything seems to be fine and working. other than **wp_remote_post**, i tried **CURL** too.

What i am doing wrong.

see my post man request:

[image: postman request image]

**PS:** The blog is present in sub folder of the project root. is this causing the problem?

Comment: Have you checked what the `wp_remote_post()` function actually returns? If something goes wrong, it should return a `WP_Error` object that might give you some more insight.

Comment: yeah. it is giving me 404 error. " The requested URL /feed/blogAPI was not found on this server. "

Comment: Are you sure that there's no typos in the URL? Correct casing?

Comment: correct I tried same url from postman. no typos

Comment: You got no record in the servers hosts file that overrides the remote hostname? Can the server access that URL from curl from the terminal?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Wouldn't it override the remote hostname in postman as well if that was the problem?

Comment: It depends on your setup. If you run your code from your local computer, yes, but if you run it from another computer or from a virtual machine, it might not (depending on your NIC setup).

Comment: I've tried your code with the url in Postman and it seems to be working fine. Could you show us your `$url` variable without changing it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the error is due to requesting same origin as remote, i.e my controller is at https://dev.kidengage.com/feed/blogAPI.

But my wordpress is in subfolder of root directory which is at https://dev.kidengage.com/blog.

so using **wp_remote_post** will result in funky response.

I ended up storing the array using like below directly from wordpress to another db which my root is using.

```
        global $wpdb;

        $newdb = new wpdb('username','password','dagtabasename','localhost');
        $newdb->show_errors();

        $postExist= $newdb->get_row("select * from blogMaster where postID=$post_ID");

        if(empty($postExist)){

            $insert=array(
                "postID" => $post_ID,
                "postTitle" => $post_after->post_title,
                "postContent" => $post_after->post_content ,
                "postExcerpt" =>  $post_after->post_excerpt,
                "postType" =>  $post_after->post_type,
                "postGuid" => $post_after->guid ,
                "postPermLink" =>  $permLink,
                "postThumb" =>  $thumbLarge,
                "postAuthorName" => $authorName,
                "postAuthorPic" => $authorURL ,
                "postStatus" => $post_after->post_status,
                "postDate" =>  $post_after->post_date,
                "postModified" =>  $post_after->post_modified
            );


            $newdb->insert("blogMaster",$insert);    

        }
```